# Object alignment between Viewport and Render are different

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I am loving learning to use Blender for visualization of biological samples.

However, I have run into a problem. In the Viewport, my models are aligned with my input data, as below:

[image]

In the rendered image, the models are misaligned, as below:

[image]

The pink model (red arrow) should coincide with the grey circle (blue arrow) in the 2D image.

I have almost no experience with rendering and have no ideas about where this discrepancy comes from, which makes getting started with troubleshooting very challenging.

I'd appreciate any input that would point me in the right direction.

Thanks!!
Sam

Comment: please share your file

Comment: Is it animated? are you viewing the same frame that is rendering?

Answer (score 1):

My guess: the misalignment is caused by perspective and different viewing angles. You look at your objects in the Viewport and in Render Camera from different sides, so what looks like "alignment" in the Viewport may actually be a perspective illusion. The best way to check it is to upload your .blend file for examination.